# hide content from preview text from HTML email

Tags: html, html-email

I have a navigation at the top of my HTML email, but I want to hide it because otherwise it will always appear in the preview text of the email client, is there as simple to hide it only in the preview text?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a preview text" defined in an html email format. It is up to the clients implementation what to visualize. So there cannot be a general answer for that.

Comment: Check this link I found to 'hide preheader text' - https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/tips-for-coding-email-preheaders

Answer (score 11):

Best way to control what preview (or preheader) text appears is to add your own directly after the opening `<body>` tag of the email code:

```
<body>
    <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">
        Add your preview text here so it appears instead of your navigation text.
    </div>
    <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->

    ... Email Body ....

</body>
```

More on [preheader text on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support).